# Writing to ~/Documents folder in Node.js on macOS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, path, home-directory

In Node.js, I am attempting to write into the `Documents` folder of the user (on macOS):

```
var logger = fs.createWriteStream('~/Documents/somefolderwhichexists/'+title+'.txt');
```

This gives me an error, but I am not sure what is wrong. The error says:

> Uncaught Exception: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

How could I use an absolute path here? Or what is my mistake?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `~` is a shorthand, to your *home directory*, expanded by the Bash shell. You need to use a fully defined path *or* get the current user name (or home path) dynamically.

To get the current user home path, ty this:

```
var home = require("os").homedir();
var logpath = home + '/Documents/somefolderwhichexists/' + title + '.txt';
var logger = fs.createWriteStream(logpath);
```

Comment: @GeorgeWelder I provided a better alternative, getting the user home directory in platform agnostic way. Please try this as well when you get a chance :)

Comment: I don't recommend concatenating paths without using `path.join()` or `path.resolve()` regardless of the app not being cross-platform.